# Custom plugin doesn't show in admin menu - when code added, displays an empty page

Tags: php, functions

my customer has this plugin: http://www.davmo.software/public/uverova-kalkulacka_v2.zip

When installed, it doesn't have a link in the menu in the administration.

I changed the $var variable in the 'uverovakalkulacka' to the correct path and added this to the plugin's index.php - right above the 'uverovakalkulacka' function declaration:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'uverovakalkulacka_menu');

function uverovakalkulacka_menu(){

   add_menu_page(
      'Úvěrová kalkulačka', // Page title
      'Úvěrová kalkulačka', // Menu title
      'manage_options', // Capability required to access the page
      'uverova-kalkulacka', // Menu slug
      'uverovakalkulacka' // Callback function to render the page
   );
}
```

This makes the plugin appear in the menu but the page when the link is clicked is empty. The function 'uverovakalkulacka' doesn't seem to be intended for this - or is it a problem with PHP version or WP version? Where do I go from here? The original author is unavailable and my customer says it used to work and I'm not a PHP guru:)

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the plugin is not meant to have a page in the administration. It just generates some HTML code from the [uverovakalkulacka] shortcode based on the contents of settings.json which is supposed to be edited manually. Thank you for your time.